# How to check for exponential values in Javascript

Tags: javascript, math

I am streaming data from a CSV file and I am pushing certain values to an array. Some of these values are very large, and may be exported as exponential values (e.g. 5.02041E+12) and some may be normal values.
I'd like to have an if statement that checks to see if these values are exponential or not, and if they are I will pass them to a function that converts them into 'normal' numbers (e.g. 5020410000000). Is there a quick way to do this?

(These values are passed to an API call which is why they need to be converted to 'normal' values)

Example of what this may look like:

```
valueOne = 5.02041E+12;
valueTwo = 1234;

if (valueOne.isExponential) {
  **pass to converting function**
}

//Output = 5020410000000

if (valueTwo.isExponential) {
  **pass to converting function**
}

//Output = 1234 (unchanged)
```

I'd expect all values in the array to therefore be 'normal' values (i.e. NOT is exponential form)

Comment: Could you provide a sample input please?

Comment: @JonasWilms Edited just now- hopefully this adds some clarirty

Comment: It would simpler don't check but just explicitly represent *all* values in "normal" form

Comment: Do `console.log(valueTwo)` and be surprised.

Comment: @MBo trouble is if non-exponential values are passed to my function that converts them to 'normal' values, the function breaks. I thought it would be easier to add a simple check for exponential values rather than refactor my converting function

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just use [toPrecision](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toPrecision) on every number and ensure it converts

```
const valueOne = 5.02041E+12;
const valueTwo = 1234;

const precisionValueOne = valueOne.toPrecision(); // "5020410000000"
const precisionValue2 = valueTwo.toPrecision(); // "1234"
```

You can then, optionally convert it back to numbers:

```
sanitizedValueOne = Number(precisionValueOne); // 5020410000000
sanitizedValueTwo = Number(precisionValueTwo); // 1234
```

Comment: Glad to hear! Feel free to mark it as the accepted answer for other people who are coming here to see.

Comment: Read what you link: *If the precision argument is omitted, behaves as `Number.prototype.toString()`.* - and that is exactly what you are doing.

Comment: Let's leave interpretations aside.
Here's what I was thinking: the problem at hand was a bit different than the question formulated: OP was trying to represent numbers in a certain way, rather than perform calculations on top of it. Using `toPrecision` without parameters serves the initial goal, however, I also speculated that he might need to reformat it later on. using `toPrecision` with an argument can achieve this goal without changing the method and that's why avoiding `toString` seemed like the logical step.

Answer (score 1):

Numbers are numbers, the values `5.02041E+12` and `5020410000000` do not differ internally:

```js
// values in code:
var withe=5.02041E+12;
var withoute=5020410000000;
console.log(withe,"?=",withoute,withe===withoute);

// values parsed from strings:
var stringwithe="5.02041E+12";
var stringwithoute="5020410000000";
var a=parseFloat(stringwithe);
var b=parseFloat(stringwithoute);
console.log(a,"?=",b,a===b);
```

And you can also see that when you simply display a number, it will not use the scientific notation by default, actually you would have to ask for it via using [`toExponential()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toExponential)

---

One thing you can worry about is the internal precision of `Number`. It has a method [`isSafeInteger()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/isSafeInteger) and various fields, like [`MAX_SAFE_INTEGER`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/MAX_SAFE_INTEGER). Surpassing that value can lead to unexpected results:

```js
var a=Number.MAX_SAFE_INTEGER;
console.log("This is safe:",a,Number.isSafeInteger(a));
a++;
for(var i=0;i<5;i++)
  console.log("These are not:",a++,Number.isSafeInteger(a));
```

So the loop can not increment `a` any further, because there is no such number as `9007199254740993` here. The next number which exists after `9007199254740992` is `9007199254740994`. But these numbers are more than 1000x greater than the `5020410000000` in the question.

Comment: This is very helpful information and I will keep this in mind in future, thank you. However I cannot have my values in exponential form as I will be making an API call with the values

Comment: @CalebWhittington *However I cannot have my values in exponential form as I will be making an API call with the values* - you will not, that is also visible from the console logs (have you clicked on the "Run code snippet" buttons?). Your problem practically does not exist. If you do not believe in the code snippets, try writing `5.02041E+12.toString()` into a JavaScript console. `toPrecision()` has another use actually, check the docs: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toPrecision

Answer (score 0):

Do a RegExp match for `E+` and probably for `E-`

The 'number' you are starting with must be text, but you should do a bit of sanity checking too.
Might be a good idea to check whether it is larger than MaxInt before you try any Math-based conversions.

Comment: You can't match a numbers with regexps and converting it to string will loose the E matcher

Comment: @silicakes  Either these are JS `Number`s to begin with, or they are text. If they are `Number`s then no conversion is needed...